# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when parsing json, but code still continues to run

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json file called myjson.json which looks like this:

```
{
    "num": 5
}
```

I now make an http request to get this json:

```
   let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   let url = "http://localhost/myjson.json";
   http.open("GET", url);

   http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {

       if(http.status === 200){
         try{
          let {num} = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
          console.log(num); //This Prints The Number 5 in the console
         }catch(err){
           console.log('Error parsing the num: ' + err); //*This runs as well. The err = SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
         }
       }else{
         console.log('Error retrieving the num: ' + http.status);
      }
   }

   http.send();
```

So the number 5 is shown in the console so it seems to have parse properly, but I get the following error in the console:

```
Error parsing the index : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

So it seems to work, but this error shows up. What can I do to remove this error?

Comment: What does printing `http.responseText` give?
And you may try without destructuring `num`, eg. `let num = JSON.parse(http.responseText);` then `num = num.num`...

Comment: It displays the exact same contents of the myjson.json file

Comment: The message "*Error parsing the index*" doesn't come from the code you posted